# Compare two strings with multiple lines

Tags: powershell, compare

I am having two strings. If the strings are equal then nothing to do , the else statement is fired.
Just it works for in single-line format. but if the strings multiple lines like below then it does not work. Where am I do wrong ?

For example `$myvar`:

`log.txt`:

```
15732: 19/Jan/2019 15:40:06.969 ERROR message -outofmemory
```

`log_2.txt`:

```
15732: 19/Jan/2019 15:40:06.969 ERROR message -fatal error 01 (122)
```

Here is my script:

```
$myvar

if (!($myvar)) {
    Write-Host "No exception info to report" -BackgroundColor Green
} else {
    $InputString = $myvar
    $StringToMatch = Get-Content C:\ftp_file\report\dump.txt
    if ($InputString -eq $StringToMatch) {
        Write-Host "it will not be sent mail because same error message $($InputString)" -BackgroundColor Green
    } else {
        Write-Host "it will be sent mail" -BackgroundColor Cyan
        Send-Mail blah blah..
        #Export myvar variable again
        "$myvar" | Out-File -FilePath C:\ftp_file\report\dump.txt
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `Get-Content` with the `-Raw` switch to get the file content as one single string. Without it, it returns an string array (the content split on newlines). Besides that, what is in your `$StringToMatch` string. If that is something that should be found somewhere in the content of the file, you will be better of using a regular expression like `if ($StringToMatch -match [Regex]::Escape($InputString))`.

Comment: `$StringToMatch` string same as `$myvar`

Comment: I don't folow that comment I'm afraid.. Does that mean `$myvar` should be completely equal to `$StringToMatch` ? In that case, you can use the `-eq` comparison operator, but you will still need to use `Get-Content -Raw`

Comment: Like you said I have tested it. But no luck.

Comment: The example strings for `$myvar` are all just one line. Where is the multiple lines in there?

Comment: Ok man I have used `if ($StringToMatch -match [Regex]::Escape($InputString))` . it works any conditions.